# Please help: How to make a PHP form for the following HTML5

Tags: php, html, forms

I am trying to make a PHP form to the following HTML5, I am a total newbie to PHP and not a "progammer" I have tried to make it work, however am totally at a lose TO correspond this with a "contact.php file"

I am trying to make a form for the following that when sent will have the attribute options selected

```
    <div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Choose Location</label>
     <div class="col-md-9">
      <select class="form-control">
       <option>Asia</option>
       <option>Australasia</option>                                
       <option>Europe</option>
       <option>Latam</option>
       <option>Middle East</option>
       <option>USA</option>                                    
      </select>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions fluid">
     <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
      <button type="submit" class="btn green">Submit</button>
      button type="button" class="btn default">Cancel</button>                              
     </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your HTML in 'form' tag, and there's 1 opening 'button' tag missing. See the adjusted code below:

```
<form action="contact-submit-handler.php" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Choose Location</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <select class="form-control">
                <option>Asia</option>
                <option>Australasia</option>
                <option>Europe</option>
                <option>Latam</option>
                <option>Middle East</option>
                <option>USA</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions fluid">
        <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
            <button type="submit" class="btn green">Submit</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn default">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to open the tag for Cancel button

Cancel